# How to get number value of button being pressed?

Tags: javascript

How do I get the value of the btns event, it is currently printing as such `<button>8</button>` in the dev log at the moment, I am trying to get it to print the value 8.

```js
//create number array
const Numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "+", "-", "/", ".", "="];

const btnContainer = document.querySelector(".button-container");

//loop into button array
for (let i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++) {
  //create button elements in for loop
  const button = document.createElement("button");

  button.innerText = Numbers[i];

  //render buttons to DOM at button-container
  for (let j = 0; j < Numbers.length; j++) {
    btnContainer.appendChild(button);
  }
}

const btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");
console.log(btn);

//loop through array usin for of
const screen = document.querySelector(".input-screen");

for (const btns of btn) {
  //press button by index
  btns.addEventListener("click", (num) => {
    const numValue = num.target.innerText;
    console.log(numValue);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-screen">
    <div class="button-container"></div>
    <div class="symbol-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buttons don't typically have a value attribute; have you tried innerText or innerHTML? Hard to tell without seeing your html.

Comment: `num.target.innerText`

Comment: @Barmar - thanks your answer worked, I am going  as little as HTML as I can to up my javascript skills, so I updated my code for you to see the full picture

Comment: What's the problem now? The code seems to work.

Comment: You changed the code, but the question still has the output from the original code.

Comment: There is no issue, just showing full code, that is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");
console.log(btn);

const screen = document.querySelector(".input-screen");

for (const btns of btn) {
  btns.addEventListener("click", (num) => {
    const numValue = num.target.textContent; // or num.target.innerText
    console.log(numValue); // This will print the text inside the button, like '8'
  });
}
```